# How to find and flag if there are values after a 'certain value' horizontally

Tags: sas, data-cleaning

```
data Have;
input col1 $ col2 $ col3 $ col4 $ col5 $ col6 $ col7 $ col8 $ col9 $ col10 $;
cards;
PM MM JM MM PM PB . . PM .
PM MM JM MM PM PB JM . . .
PM MM JM MM PM MB PM MM . .
PM MM JM MM PM PM MM MB . .
PM MM JM MM PM PM MM PB . .
;
```

Hello all, I was not clear in my details and goal in my last post. So, I am reposting this again.

The data look like what I have in 'Have' above.

**Want:**

I need to find and flag records that have any value occurring after 'PB' or 'MB', if there is any non-missing value occurring after values 'PB' or 'MB' horizontally, I want to flag it.

```
                                        flag 
PM MM JM MM PM PB . . PM .               1
PM MM JM MM PM PB JM . . .               1
PM MM JM MM PM MB PM MM . .              1
PM MM JM MM PM PM MM MB .                0
PM MM JM MM PM PM MM PB .                0
```

Comment: Can a row have multiple `MB` or `PB` or both? If so, is the rule for occurring after 1st or last occurrence? Can a row have neither `MB` nor `PB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can once again concatenate all the columns and perform a check.  The `CATX` function concatenates with a delimiter. If in the concatenation a PB or MB is found with a delimiter after it, then you know there is another value after the delimiter.

```
  string = catx('~', of col1-col10);
  flag = index(string, 'PB~')>0 or index(string,'MB~')>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the indicator values.  Then if found search for a non-missing value.

```
data have;
  input (col1-col10) ($);
cards;
PM MM JM MM PM PB . . PM .
PM MM JM MM PM PB JM . . .
PM MM JM MM PM MB PM MM . .
PM MM JM MM PM PM MM MB . .
PM MM JM MM PM PM MM PB . .
;

data want;
  set have;
  array col col1-col10;
  do index=1 to dim(col) until(found);
    found = col[index] in ('PB' 'MB');
  end;
  if found then do index=index+1 to dim(col) until(not found);
    found =  missing(col[index]);
  end;
  flag= not found;
  *drop index found;
run;
```

Results:

[image]